# Why did Harrison Ford portray Han Solo as so likeable?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

You have to really absorb the movie over a number of viewings to see what JJ Abrams and Lawrence Kasden did to Han Solo's character. This question very specifically asks for documentation of the motivation for specific aspects of the abstract art of the film. Such as interviews with the writers and other such sources that are more revealing.

---

In The Force Awakens, we see Han Solo

> resorting to a bandit's life because his wife could not stand him. We see two groups of aliens try to kill him for double dealing. We see that he sent several crewmen to death trying to smuggle vicious animals. We see his son throw violent tantrums, order executions, personally torture people, and then even kill his own father, Han.

But yet

> the audience swoons when Han appears to retake the Millennium Falcon. Rey adores Han as a father figure. Maz and Han show a soft kindness in their friendship. And Han's last expression of life is to gently caress his son's cheek as his son is murdering him.

Clearly a decision was made to portray Han Solo as a kind, likeable person despite all the above described darkness that we all seem to ignore.  Even Leia

> blames Ben Solo's problems on her father Darth Vader instead of bundling Ben Solo in the long list of people who get so tormented by Han Solo's behavior that they want to kill him.

Who made the decision to portray Han Solo as such a loveable person that the audience cannot even imagine considering him to be evil?

Did George Lucas define Han this way? Is it just an unintended byproduct of having Harrison Ford as the actor? Or does JJ Abrams conjure up evil that is out of character? What documentation exists on this topic?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think you're conjuring evil where even J.J.Abrams didn't mean to. Most "bad" things you list aren't Han's fault.

Comment: Don't blame the father for the actions of the son

Comment: @DVK I have seen the movie 4 times in 3D. It is larger than life and the story has so much power that views like this become possible. Note how reflexively you defend him. We all love and forgive him and blame everyone else for his problems. With the glaring exception of Ben Solo and the others listed above who have a harshly different view.

Comment: @CodeMed - Han is one of my least favorite characters personality-wise (he is my favorite entertainment wise, but due to his sarcasm, not de to his stellar qualities). So I'm pretty much an unbiased observer here, bit "reflexive defender".

Comment: If you don't think people that do bad things can't be likeable around others, then you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of human nature. Also, Han shot first. ;)

Comment: @CreationEdge The fact that he does bad things that cause people to hate him is at the heart of this question.  People around him at first love him, then often grow to hate him.  These aspects of his character were not as apparent in the earlier movies.  In fact, the current movie moves so quickly that you almost have to watch it many times before starting to take in abstractions like this.

Comment: You've not listed anyone who loved him and now *hates* him. There's no evidence of that in the shows. The only characters that *don't* like him are villains. If you're going to present such a strong stance, you should have something to back it up. You'll also note that he and Chewbacca are *friends until the end*. Is Chewbacca also evil? You could have a valid question here, but you've taken such a strong, polarizing, unsubstantiated stance, which is why it's poorly received. Plus, why bring Ford's acting into it? You're all over the place.

Comment: @CreationEdge Ben loved him then hates him.  Chewy is his employee and also another species, plus the only long term close connection Han has.  My observation is abstract.  It is not all over the place.  Instead, it takes in imagery and comments on it.  Go see the movie a couple more times then write your own answer.  I would be happy to read it.  I am glad the post got downvoted.  The downvotes only support my premise that people defend Han vehemently even though he has no one in his actual personal space over the long term besides Chewy, and even though so many grow to hate him.

Comment: You haven't shown that many people grow to hate him. Your only real example is of somebody whose mind has been twisted by the dark side? No, I don't need to see the movie over and over to try and understand your "abstract" notions, I'm quite familiar with thematic elements, writing, and characterization. Enough so to see that your question is *poor*, and that it *could* be better, but you're also absolutely refusing to improve it per anyone's suggestions, and instead are digging in your heels and accusing others of not getting it. I'm done here, you can't argue with fanatics.

Comment: @CreationEdge  I am not arguing with fanatics.  I just asked a question and am amused by the vehement responses.  No need to get emotional.  People getting intense in response to a simple question only means this is a good question.  People get intense in response to Han Solo, but in the end all he has is his dog Chewy.  His own son kills him.

Comment: One sort of suspects trolling here, especially with the suggestion that haters watch the film in 3D.

Comment: The author's edit to add the note at the top of the question is just breathtaking. "Everyone thinks my question is bad, therefore it is good." The denial is strong with this one.

Comment: Han is the archetypal "**lovable rogue**". So much so, he's mentioned on both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovable_rogue) and [TVtropes'](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LovableRogue?from=Main.LoveableRogue) pages on the "lovable rogue" character archetype. He does bad things - but with a charming smile while being loyal to his friends, so the audience thinks it's okay, even though maybe they shouldn't.

Comment: Just wondering, do people who get headaches from 3D movies still have to watch it in 3D? That seems a little mean.

Answer (score 34):

Actually, it seems you're severely misinterpreting the events of the film to portray Han as far more evil than he is. Let's address ALL your points one by one.

- resorting to a bandit's life

  No. He's a smuggler (at worst) and shipping pilot (at best). A [bandit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banditry) usually carries a context of someone who attacks people as part of their occupation. It does NOT include people who exercise self-defense. And in TFA he very clearly says he always **talks** his way out of situations, not **shoots** his way out!

  If you say "outlaw", you MAAAAAY be closer to the truth - except in TFA, there's little indication that Han is doing anything muchly illegal. No narcotics contraband at least, and no working for local crime lord (he borrowed money from some, but that's different ethics wise).
- because his wife could not stand him.

  No, he turned smuggler because that's the only way he knows how to make money (and he showed positive qualities and strength of character by NOT mooching off of his rich high-power ex-wife).

  His wife can't stand him because they were both two in-love-idiots with incompatible personalities, who never should have gotten involved no matter what chemistry they had :)

  Chemistry.com or OKCupid would NEVER pair the two of them up.
- We see two groups of aliens try to kill him for double dealing.

  Yes. He's a con man. Always has been. Mind you, conning two **gangsters** (he ain't swindling honest citizens here, or EVER in all of canon), doesn't strike me as the depth of all possible evil. May not win him BBB best businessman award, granted. But far from evil.
- We see that he sent several crewmen to death trying to smuggle vicious animals.

  He hired people for dangerous job who volunteered to do it. That doesn't make him a bleeding heart, but hardly makes him a bad person. The worst thing about him you can say is that he's a bit too *blasé* about it - but he's equally *blasé* about his own life and death, so it's a coping mechanism/sarcastic personality trait and not a lack of empathy.
- We see his son throw violent tantrums, order executions, personally torture people, and then even kill his own father, Han.

  Yes. Which is pretty much what happens when you're unbalanced Dark Side user. Which Han had absolutely nothing to do with - that's between Luke and Snoke. You don't see HAN throwing temper tantrums, ordering executions and torturing people as parental example, do you?
- The audience swoons when Han appears to retake the Millennium Falcon.

  They don't swoon because Han is a Christ figure (yet). They swoon because Han as a character means excitement and wit - two main components of good entertainment. It also means still-somewhat-sexy Harrison Ford, which doesn't hurt with the half of the audience that's romantically into males.

  Having said that, being a bit rough around the edges makes Han MORE sexually attractive. Google around for research into relationship between female attraction and what's known as "dark triad" of personality traits. Han visibly demonstrates a pretty big chunk of Dark Triad, especially on the surface.
- Rey adores Han as a father figure.

  That's because he reminds her of **her** - hardscrabble survivor.

  > In addition to anger, their captor’s voice was filled with righteous indignation. To Rey, it sounded a little forced. Definitely this man was not now and never had been a stormtrooper or anything like it. **What he had been, maybe, was someone not unlike herself. A bit of a businessman, a bit of a con man, a bit of an adventurer. And since he was older, it was only reasonable to assume that he had been a bit more of all of those things than herself**. (novelization)
- Maz and Han show a soft kindness in their friendship.

  I'm not sure what your point, or exact objection here is?

  - Han is always softly kind to people he's close to. He's the best friend you want, ever. He risked his life to save Luke over DS1. He risked his life to stick by Luke and Leia ever since DS1. He volunteered to lead near-suicide mission on Endor sanctuary moon for Leia. He was willing to step aside to let Luke and Leia passionately love each other. EWWWW! He's softly kind to Chewie, where it counts.

    Going down canon ladder, he gave his all to help Bria Tharen, repeatedly. He risked his life to save Salla.

  If you're objecting to Maz liking Han:

  - she's an ex-pirate. Compared to her, Han is practically a saint :)
  - She is a devotee of Light side. Han kinda did lots of things to help Light win.
- And Han's last expression of life is to gently caress his son's cheek as his son is murdering him.

  Yes, it's called being a parent. I'm not sure what your point is? He is misguided to love a son such as Ben, but in normal real life, parents of psychopaths still love them.
- Clearly a decision was made to portray Han Solo as a kind, likable person despite all the above described darkness that we all seem to ignore.

  Yes, it's called an archetype. A scoundrel with a heart of gold. Very Campbellian, and has been the case since Episode IV.
- Even Leia  blames Ben Solo's problems on her father Darth Vader instead of bundling Ben Solo in the long list of people who get so tormented by Han Solo's behavior that they want to kill him.

  You present absolutely zero evidence that Han or his behavior had **any** negative effect on Ben. Probably, because the canon offers zero evidence to back up that weird theory. One possible bad influence may have been if they either (a) fought each other while married - but knowing Leia, I can't POSSIBLY ascribe more responsibility to Han than her - see them bickering ever since Episode VI. She's right up there with him in sass and insults; (b) divorcing, **assuming** - which we don't know for sure - that it happened before he was an adult. But again, knowing Leia, it clearly would have been at least as much her fault as his - they are simply both strong unbendable personalities.

  However, Ben didn't start out a psychopath as Solo. He got twisted into that by being a Force-user with volatile personality. Remind you of someone? Yep, Anakin bloody creep Skywalker.
- Who made the decision to portray Han Solo as such a loveable person that the audience cannot even imagine considering him to be evil?
- > Did George Lucas define Han this way?

  Yes. Or even more significantly, Joseph Campbell did.

  Remember that the entire Star Wars is completely, unabashedly following the Campbell's Hero's Journey.

  Han is the "**Shapeshifter** (the Hero isn't sure if he can trust this character)" archetype.
- > *Is it just an unintended byproduct of having Harrison Ford as the actor?*

  I would say it's the opposite. Ford is simply an amazing vehicle for channeling that archetype. Even as offscreen person, he has dry wit.
- > *Or does JJ Abrams conjure up evil that is out of character? What documentation exists on this topic?*

  J.J. Abrams basically portrayed Han **well within character**, merely in darker circumstances.

  Remember the whole "Han Shot First" blowup? The main point was that Han shooting first was an important characterization. He's not a psychopath (he doesn't just randomly shoot people - Greedo was about to shoot HIM), but he's also a rough character willing to pull the trigger first because he knows he lives in a world where if you don't, you may not live long enough to pull it at all. No wallflower by any stretch.

Comment: Han was killed by his own darkness. But we all love him so much that we defend him reflexively instead of seeing his darkness. My question is about who made the decision to define Han as so likeable. ... Before The Force Awakens, I never imagined that Han had a dark side. And I had to watch the movie 4 times before starting to ponder it.

Comment: @CodeMed - that's your personal interpretation - in many cases clearly contradicted by canon facts as I show. Sorry, but I gotta go with where canon facts lead me.

Comment: See the movie many times and ponder the Force. Also, this is JJ Abrams' artwork, to be pondered as artwork. By contrast, canon is like scripture that is meant contextually and not literally. But I don't need everyone to share my perceptions. It is art intended to elicit inquisitiveness from various viewpoints.

Comment: @CodeMed You asked your question and got your very well-supported answer. Don't get so miffed just because it's not the one you wanted.

Comment: Do we even know Han was being serious about the dead workers? It sounded pretty sarcastic to me.

Comment: @RogueJedi - we don't know, but it does make sense logistically so he may have been telling the truth. My main point is that yes he sounds blaze, no it isn't out of sociopathic tendensies or lack of empathy

Comment: @WolfieInu I am not miffed at all. I just think it is a left brain response to a right brain question. ... Both are valid. But to see my point a person has to take the film visually, which cannot be addressed by endless comments, so I won't waste the time. ... Go see the movie again.

Comment: @CodeMed - not sure what exactly you meant, but if you're aiming for postmodernism, I put about as much truck with that as I do with Skippy the Jedi Droid or Star Wars Holiday Special.

Comment: @CodeMed Of course, the only reason why anyone could disagree with you is down to their inferior intellect. </sarcasm> Have a downvote, son.

Comment: @  I just don't think an off-hand comment by a guy who isn't always honest should be taken as absolute, confirmed Canon. However, it's a minor thing and I agree with just about everything else you say, so +1.

Comment: Who said his wife can't stand him? They split after a family tragedy and threw themselves into their jobs, a common enough trope. They still loved each other, they just felt guilty and hurt about what happened to their child. Their dialogue was pretty clear on this.

Comment: @CreationEdge - they do admit they drive each other crazy. Their dialog together is NOT of people who can stand each other. That is orthogonal to love.

Comment: Couples can fight. The love was clearly there. The embrace, the sensing his death. The talk of bringing the son *home*, implying with *both* parents that still love each other and their wayward child. The practically start their conversation with forgiving one another's faults! There was no enmity.

Comment: @CreationEdge - So? I don't disagree with antthing you say. They still have completey incompatible personality and can't stand each other **in spite** of that.

Comment: @DVK My personal impression of their conversation is that despite probably living as cat and dog while married, they _can_ stand each other, and did so just fine up until the point when their son turned. Leia says that she shouldn't have allowed Ben to be sent away for his training; that's when she lost both him and Han. I don't see where “they can't stand each other” comes from at all—Leia just can't bear to be with Han because it reminds her of her son and her pain.

Comment: @CodeMed For the record (rereading now): if you didn't notice all the same ‘dark’ traits in Han in the original trilogy as are present in _TFA_, then you're the one who needs to go rewatch the movies, and actually pay attention to them. Han is **very explicitly** portrayed for most of the first film as a cheating smuggler who incites “I could strangle him!” feelings in most people he meets, not least Leia (with whom the feeling, attractions aside, is mutual). Han was never portrayed as particularly kind or likeable, and he's not in _TFA_ either.